# Delete SQL Statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an update sql statement that runs perfect to update a record in msaccess via vb.net.  Is there anyway to turn it into a delete statement as well?  So i have a button to update the record and if i want to Delete the record.

Code for the update:

```
Dim sqlupdate As String
' Here we use the UPDATE Statement to update the information. To be sure we are   
' updating the right record we also use the WHERE clause to be sureno information  
' is added or changed in the other records  
'sqlupdate = "UPDATE Table1 SET Title=@Title, YearofFilm=@YearofFilm, Description=@Description, Field1=@Field1 WHERE ID='" & TextBox5.Text & "'"
'WHERE YearofFilm='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
'sqlupdate = "UPDATE Table1 SET Title=@Title, YearofFilm=@YearofFilm, Description=@Description, " & "Field1=@Field1 WHERE ID='" & TextBox5.Text & "'"
sqlupdate = "UPDATE Table1 SET Title=@Title, YearofFilm=@YearofFilm, " & _
            "Description=@Description, Field1=@Field1 WHERE ID=@id"

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlupdate, con1)
' This assigns the values for our columns in the DataBase.   
' To ensure the correct values are written to the correct column  
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearofFilm", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", TextBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field1", TextBox4.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text))

' This is what actually writes our changes to the DataBase.  
' You have to open the connection, execute the commands and  
' then close connection.  
con1.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con1.Close()

' This are subs in Module1, to clear all the TextBoxes on the form  
' and refresh the DataGridView on the MainForm to show our new records.  
ClearTextBox(Me)
Me.Close()
RefreshDGV()
```

Comment: It is simple sql syntax. Look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Comment: You have some older code there in the comments that's crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. Just get rid of that stuff.

Comment: Seconding that. Be wary with adding textbox text to sql statements without validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be something like this

```
Dim ConnString As String = "yourConnectionString"

Dim SqlString As String = "Delete From Table1 Where ID=@id"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)

  Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text))

   conn.Open()

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()

  End Using

End Using
```

Greetings!

Comment: It works with Access, but the standard (accepted also by Access) doesn't include the *

Comment: Right, sorry, should be so "Delete From Table1 Where ID=@id"